Are GPU-specific hardware questions on topic?
This question appears to be about building a mining rig and installing a bunch of GPU cards. Something goes wrong, and the OP has a question.
Arguments for on-topic:

Installing a bunch of GPUs is something that ordinary users are unlikely to do (but there are certainly other computing activities that might need multiple GPUs)
The user's purpose for doing this is clearly to build a mining rig, something that other site users are likely to have done

Arguments for off-topic:

None of the immediate content of the question has anything to do with Bitcoin (or other cryptocurrency)
Superuser is a well-established site where hardware questions like this are specifically on-topic

I suggest that if a consensus is reached on this point (or generally on hardware-specific questions), that the decision is added to the on-topic help center page (in whichever section is decided). Right now there is no guidance for topicality of purely hardware/OS questions.

I'd say that this is mainly off-topic because it simply concerns hardware more than crypto currencies. The fact that he plans to mine a cryptocurrency is irrelevant in this question and not important. There is no mention of mining as well...

I don't like to really consider other sites and overlap when talking about what's on-topic during a beta. Well, I consider them, but I don't like ruling out questions purely because another site would accept them.
A resounding theme here is, pure hardware might be interesting to people into crypto currencies, but if the question has nothing to do with Bitcoin (or others), then they're asking in hopes of getting access to this sort of niche knowledge that they presume folks here would have. That's not what we're here for, we're here to talk about Bitcoin.
Hard to set a blanket rule because I think we'll see our fair share of exceptions, but this is a good acid test:

Are they here to basically pick our brains by just tacking on Bitcoin in context?

... then you're probably in the off-topic range of things. Or:

Is this question basically the same if we take Bitcoin out of its context?

... again, pretty square in off-topic I'd say, most of the time. 
I can probably come up with a better litmus test after a few more cups of coffee, but that's where I'm thinking it would land. 

I like that test, "Could the same question be asked if the context of Bitcoin were omitted?". Perhaps we should put that in our topic guidance.
